# Create Email address from names Compiler Design

Tags: flex4, yacc, lex, context-free-grammar, compiler-construction

**Creating email addresses form names**

You have given a file containing names of several persons. The file will have exactly one name is each line. You need to create email address ending with @bitmesra.ac.in from those names.
the rule for creating email address is defined below: A name will be expressed in the following form:
............

Let F(s) denote the first character of string s.
so, email id will be     F(string 1)*F(string 2)*........._lastString@bitmesra.ac.in
Some names and their corresponding email id's are listed below as an example

Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar       s_r_tendulkar@bitmesra.ac.in
Rahul S Dravid                r_s_dravid@bitmesra.ac.in

You need to generate a grammer for this.

note: there may multiple spaces b/w names.

**My Code is here**

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cctype>
int main()
{
char str1[100],str2[100];
char str3[] = "@bitmesra.ac.in";
while(gets(str1))
{
    int index,k=0;
    str2[k] = tolower(str1[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<strlen(str1);i++)
    {
        if(str1[i]==' ')
        {
            index = i;
            if(isalpha(str1[i+1]))
            {
                k++;
                str2[k] = '_';
                k++;
                str2[k] = tolower(str1[i+1]);
            }
        }
    }

    index= index + 2;
    for(int i=index;str1[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        k++;
        str2[k] = tolower(str1[i]);
    }
    str2[++k] = '\0';
    strcat(str2,str3);
    printf("%s\n",str2);
}
return 0;
}
```

How to write CFG Grammar For this.....

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
optnamelist:                  /* file can be empty */
    |    namelist             /* do nothing */

namelist: nameseq NL          /* process vector */
    |    namelist NL nameseq  /* process vector */

nameseq: name                 /* create vector and add element 1 */
    |    nameseq name         /* add element to vector */
```

The lexer should take care of white spaces (eat them). The NL token is a sequence of one or more newlines.
If you add names to the end of a vector, you'll have to process it backward.
Your code implies you're writing this in C. So you could use a fixed sized Vector, e.g.

```
#define MAX_NAMES   100   /* this will probably be enough :-) */
static int actpos;
static char *myVector[MAX_NAMES];

...
/* "create" vector */
memset(myVector, 0, MAX_NAMES * sizeof(char *));
actpos = 0;

...
/* add name to vector */
myVector[actpos] = strdup($1 /* or $2 */);
if (myVector[actpos) == NULL) ... /* out of memory */
actpos++;
if (actpos >= MAX_NAMES) ... /* name too long */

...
/* process vector */
for (i = actpos - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    /* add myVector[i][0] to e-mail address */
    free(myVector[i]);
}
/* add myVector[0] to e-mail address */
free(myVector[0]);
```